# reversing list using slicing [ : 0:-1] in Python

Tags: python

I am confused in the list slicing in Python.

For a list

```
L=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I wanted to reverse the list and could get the answer by

```
L[::-1]
```

getting `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`.

However, when I tried

```
L[10:0:-1]
```

I got `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` without `0`. 
Neither `L[10:1:-1]` nor `L[10:-1:-1]` give the answer.

On the other hand, `L[200::-1]`, `L[10:-12:-1]`
gives correct answer, though `L[200]`, `L[-12]` is out of bounds.

I would like to understand the underlying logic of Python
for this case. 
Thank you.

Comment: `L[10::-1]` would work as well

Comment: This is a better answer than I could provide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/16959 basically the middle argument is the number of elements from the right - 1

Comment: Regarding the "out of bounds" indexing: if the slice indices exceed the size of the list, Python just takes as much as there is available (i.e. the whole list).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: Similar issue to: why are 'L[nn:0:-1]' and 'L[nn::-1]' not equivalent (where nn=len(L))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 >>> L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 >>> L[1:3]
 [1, 2]
```

index `3` is excluding

```
>>> L[0:10:1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

index `10` is excluding, and if you want to select all,you should use:

```
>>>L[0:11:1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

but you can not get `L[11]`,it will be throw `IndexError`,because you only have 11 elements,the max index is 10, the reason `L[0:11:1]` will not out of bound because this slice will not access to `L[11]` only from index 0 to 10.

```
>>> L[10:0:-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

`-1` is a step of slice reversely,also `0` is excluding,

and `L[10:-1:-1]` is equivalent to `L[10:10:-1]` ,because the first `-1` means the last index of L

```
>>> L[10:-12:-1]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

index `-11` is equivalent to index `0`, index `-12` is equivalent to index before `0`

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a list for example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

If you try to slice it using positive indices,

```
newa = a[1:5]
```

This will result in

```
newa = [2, 3, 4, 4]
```

This is because, in the above case slicing occurs like this, a[inclusive : exclusive], first index is included and slicing begins from this index, and end just one index before the index(5), exclusive(remember). This is just the way how list slicing works.

To get last two values of the list a,

```
newa = [6 : ]
```

Here, the index starts from 6(inclusive) and ends till end of the list.

If you are keen in using negative indexing in lists as Python offers to ease up indexing, know once and for all the inclusive and exclusive thing about slicing.

For same example above, to get last two numbers of the list using negative index, what we do is,

```
newa = a[-2 : ]
```

In the case of positive indexing, the index begins at 0 while for negative indexing, the index is at -1, -2 and so on. So in the above example, starting from second last number in the list, slice till the end of the list, is what is understood.

Now, to reverse the list, one could do,

```
print a.reverse()
[9, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

In slicing way, list can be reversed by giving it a [start, end, step] like mentioned above, but I would like to clarify it further.

```
 r = a[2: : -1]
```

This will make a new list starting with number from index 2, and till the end of the list, but since the step is -1, we decrease from index 2, till we reach 0. Hence we come up with a  reversed list of first three numbers as below:

```
r = [3, 2, 1]
```

Also, to get a whole of the list as reversed,

```
r = a[len(a): : -1]
```

This will start from 8, the length of the list, but in indices terms which begins from 0, we have 0 till 8 indices, so starting from 8th indices, it goes on decreasing in steps of -1, till the end of the list. The result is as:

```
[9, 6, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

I personally prefer to use this for reversing the list.

Answer (score 3):

For the Python list slicing syntax, `list[start:end:step]` will get a sliced list with items starting with `list[start]`, but `list[end]` is excluded. As a result, in your case, `L[10:0:-1]` will exclude `L[0]`, *i.e.*, 0, and `L[10::-1]` will work as you expect.

When the `start` or `end` is a negative number, it means it counts from the end of the list. So `list[-1]` will get the last item in the list. In your case, `L[10:-1:-1]` is equivalent to `L[10:10:-1]`. So `L[10:-1:-1]` will get `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers correctly explain what happens when list slices are used. However, I would like to touch upon the final part of the question - how does `L[200::-1]` or `L[10:-12:-1]` work even though both 200 and 12 are out of bounds of the array?

You can simply understand it this way - When slices are used to extract elements from a sequence, python ensures that the indices used within the slice are within the the length of the sequence. Hence in your case, when you specify `L[200::-1]`, what happens internally is that Python checks that the length of the sequence `L` is only **11** and hence treats the above statement as `L[10::-1]` instead. Similar argument applies to `L[10:-12:-1]`.

[This](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html) link provides a good insight into section-slices. Typically at the end of this page there is a description and an example on how to implement sequences that support extended slicing. To quote:

> slice objects now have a method **indices(length)** which, given the
>   length of a sequence, returns a (start, stop, step) tuple that can be
>   passed directly to range(). indices() handles **omitted and
>   out-of-bounds** indices in a manner consistent with regular slices
>   (and this innocuous phrase hides a welter of confusing details!).

Comment: Does it bother to actually check anything, or is it just applying min/max?